# How to round Arc edges in flutter?

Tags: flutter, canvas

I need to create an arc chart as following:

[image]

Using canvas I've created this one:

[image]

My code:

```
class CustomChartPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

    Rect drawingRect = Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2), radius: size.width / 2);


    final Paint paint2 = Paint();
    paint2.color = const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
    paint2.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint2.strokeWidth = 50;

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2), size.width / 2, paint2);

    canvas.drawArc(drawingRect,
        -pi / 2 + 0.35,
        pi - 0.35,
        false,
        greenPaint);

    canvas.drawArc(drawingRect,
        pi / 2 + 0.35,
        pi - 0.35,
        false,
        orangePaint);
  }
}
```

How can I round edges of arcs as presented on the first picture?

Comment: @pskink Will I have to calculate the chart edge coordinates and the rotation angle of semicircles?

Comment: sorry, forget it - i was wrong, see `Paint.strokeCap`

Comment: @pskink Wow wow wow! It's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

As @pskink mentioned, the solution is to use `Paint.strokeCap`, more precisely: `paint.strokeCap = StrokeCap.round`